# Django ForeignKey field ignored by graphene-django when "to" value is a string

Tags: python, django, graphene-django

Versions:

```
Python: 3.8
Django: 3.2.2
graphene-django: 2.15.0
```

The below issue worked was observed after upgrading to Django 3.2.2 from a 3.0 version.

I have an issue when using graphene-django with a ForeignKey field, it is ignored because the value of `to` is a string. By ignored, I mean it isn't converted to a GraphQL field. Here's the Django model:

```
class CableTermination(models.Model):
    cable = models.ForeignKey(
        to='dcim.Cable',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

The value of `to` is a string to avoid a circular import. This is also the only field (apart from `pk`) on this model.

I've created a DjangoObjectType from this class:

```
class CableTerminationNodeType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = CableTermination
```

I also have a type for Cable:

```
class CableNodeType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Cable
```

But on startup I see this error:

```
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphql/type/definition.py", line 214, in define_field_map
    assert isinstance(field_map, Mapping) and len(field_map) > 0, (
AssertionError: CableTerminationNodeType fields must be a mapping (dict / OrderedDict) with field names as keys or a function which returns such a mapping.
```

I've tracked this down to `field_map` having length 0. I have also observed that the converter for the above cable field is called but returns None.

This is because `field.related_model` returns the string `dcim.Cable` but the registry can only lookup by class. So ultimately, `_type` is `None` below:

```
@convert_django_field.register(models.OneToOneField)
@convert_django_field.register(models.ForeignKey)
def convert_field_to_djangomodel(field, registry=None):
    model = field.related_model

    def dynamic_type():
        _type = registry.get_type_for_model(model)
        if not _type:
            return

        return Field(_type, description=field.help_text, required=not field.null)

    return Dynamic(dynamic_type)
```

Anyone come across a similar issue? Or is there something I should be doing differently?

It appears I can workaround this by overriding the converter and loading the model with `django.apps`. So I'm wondering if this is a valid bug and fix (which I should raise a PR for) or something going wrong on my end.

```
@convert_django_field.register(models.OneToOneField)
@convert_django_field.register(models.ForeignKey)
def convert_field_to_djangomodel(field, registry=None):
    model = field.related_model
    if isinstance(model, str):
        split = model.split('.', 1)
        model = apps.get_model(app_label=split[0], model_name=split[1])

    def dynamic_type():
        _type = registry.get_type_for_model(model)
        if not _type:
            return

        return Field(_type, description=field.help_text, required=not field.null)

    return Dynamic(dynamic_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is the problem, but it isn't.

The problem is that you didn't register a Cable type. When you look into the debugger you will see that `field.related_model` is already resolved: Django does this, graphene doesn't even see the string reference.

But if you don't get the Cable model into the registry by creating a DjangoObjectType for it and import it into the schema, graphene_django cannot find it.

To make it clear and assuming the app with the CableTermination model is called "main" and your settings file is in `project/`:

`# file: dcim/schema.py`

```py
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import Cable


class CableType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Cable
```

`# main/schema.py`

```py
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import CableTermination


class CableTerminationType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = CableTermination


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    terminations = graphene.List(CableTerminationType)

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_terminations(root, info, **kwargs):
        return CableTermination.objects.all()
```

`#project/schema.py:`

```py
import graphene
import main.schema

# import the schema with the CableType, so it registers itself
import dcim.schema


class Query(main.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

`# project/settings.py`

```py
GRAPHENE = {
    "SCHEMA": 'project.schema.schema'
}
```

This is the minimal setup. Of course, if you create queries and/or mutations for the Cable model, this will resolve itself, since you will need to create a type for it.

### Update:

Can't reproduce what you're describing with Django 3.2.3. Above solution still works for me.

[image: Debugger showing resolved field.related_model]

Comment: Hi Melvyn, thanks for your response. Actually when looking in the debugger the related_model is not resolved, it's still a string. I also have already registered the Cable type (see my CableNodeType in my description). I can see this is available in the registry, so I know it's been registered, however related_model is a string so the converter performs a lookup with string value of `dcim.Cable` when the registry includes a dict where the key is the class, so the converter should be looking by `<class dcim.Cable>` instead.

Comment: Also this was not an issue until I upgraded to Django 3.2.2 (from a 3.0 version). I forgot to add this to the question, so will update it.

Comment: That would be a regression in 3.2, that would hurt a lot more than just graphene. I know you have a CableNodeType, but I assumed since it's in the other app, it's possible it's not imported into the schema. I could reproduce and fix the problem by making sure the CableNodeType (CableType in my case), would be imported into the schema. I'll check 3.2 though, I had 3.1.x still.